# Can't install Scribus 1.4

Tags: software-installation

I want to use the new version of Scribus on my Ubuntu laptop after finding it very easy to install on my old macbook.

I've added this to my software sources:

Ubuntu Maverick Meerkat (maverick or 10.10):

```
deb http://debian.scribus.net/debian/ maverick main
deb http://debian.tagancha.org/debian/ maverick main
```

As recommended here: http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Debian#Ubuntu_Maverick_Meerkat_.28maverick_or_10.10.29:

When I try and install it, it does this:

```
me@me-laptop:~$ sudo aptitude install scribus-ng
[sudo] password for me: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information      
Initializing package states... Done
Writing extended state information... Done
The following packages are BROKEN: 
scribus-ng 

The following NEW packages will be installed:

  blt{a} icc-profiles{a} libpodofo0.9.0{a} python-tk{a} tcl8.5{a} tk8.5{a} 
The following packages will be REMOVED:

  bsd-mailx{u} 

0 packages upgraded, 7 newly installed, 1 to remove and 73 not upgraded.
Need to get 50.6MB of archives. After unpacking 98.2MB will be used.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

  scribus-ng: Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but 4:4.6.2-0ubuntu5.1 is installed and it is kept back.

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Keep the following packages at their current version:
scribus-ng [Not Installed]

Score is -9881

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bsd-mailx{u} 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 73 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B of archives. After unpacking 299kB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] Y
Writing extended state information... Done
(Reading database ... 218429 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing bsd-mailx ...
Processing triggers for doc-base ...
Processing 1 removed doc-base file(s)...
Registering documents with scrollkeeper...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Reading package lists... Done             
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information      
Initializing package states... Done
Writing extended state information... Done

Package dependencies cannot be resolved
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super weird since yesterday i happen to install Scribus for my girlfriend since libreoffice does **NOT YET** have something similar to Microsoft Publisher.

I follow the guide here: http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Debian

But before you do it. Please do a `sudo aptitude purge scribus-ng`

Make sure that there are not problems when using aptitude when installing another program then do the following as the guide says:

1. Add the Repository to your list (Open the Update manager and click on Settings). the repository is **deb http://debian.scribus.net/debian/ maverick main** Close the Repository Manager and it reload the repository (It will do it automatically but if it does not then do a `sudo aptitude update` )
2. Open your Synaptic Package Manager (Am just telling you how i did it step by step) and search for Scribus. The scribus-ng will appear. Double click on it and install.

Let me know how it went.

Comment: Ha, thought I was using 10.10 but it is 10.04! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the correct repository for your installation? The installed version reported by aptitude, `4:4.6.2-0ubuntu5.1`, implies that you have Lucid, not Maverick. Maverick ships with libqtcore `4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3`, which should resolve the dependency.

Does it work if you use the Lucid repository instead?

```
deb http://debian.scribus.net/debian/ lucid main
deb http://debian.tagancha.org/debian/ lucid main
```